# dynamic arrays int printing problem - maybe not a valid memory cell

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int find_lenght(int *arrr){
    int i = 0;
    while(arrr[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
return i;
}

void init_array(int *arrr){
    arrr=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    printf("New element:");
    
    int lenght = find_lenght(arrr);
    scanf("%d", &arrr[lenght]);
    printf("Lenght = %d\n",lenght);
    
    printf("Array elements are:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++) {
        printf("%d,", arrr[i]);
    }
}

void print_array(int *arrr){
    printf("Array elements are:\n");
    int lenght = find_lenght(arrr);
    for(int i = 0; i == lenght; i++) {
        printf("%d,", arrr[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int *arr = NULL;
    init_array(arr);
    print_array(arr);
}
```

I don't know what am i missing here.
My point is to fill in and then print dynamic array

Also my taught is it's not filling the way it should, so it hasn't anything to print.

Comment: _Side note_: `arrr[i] != '\0'` --> `arrr[i] != 0`

Comment: Potential UB: In `find_lenght` what happens if all elements are nonzero?

Comment: @CraigEstey in this case `'\0'` is being converted to int. `'\0' == 0'

Comment: In `init_array` after the `malloc` the values in `arrr` are indeterminate

Comment: @0___________ yes it works but it's comparing a char constant against an `int` so less clear, IMO

Comment: In `init_array` lines 4, 5, 6 and 9 are all UB. Also not how you create an array matching the size the user inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Your `arr` pointer in main is never assigned because your `init_array` assign the address of the allocated memory (the return value of `malloc`) to the input parameter `arrr`, which is, a local variable.

You have mainly two solutions to properly achieve what you want to do. The first one (the better one in my point of view), by making your `init_array` returning the allocated memory address to be assigned:

```
int* init_array() 
{
  int* retval = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  // ... 
  return retval;
}

int main() 
{ 
  int *arr = init_array(); //< assign arr with returned value
}
```

Another way is to make your `init_array` function taking a **pointer to a pointer**, so the function can assign this pointer:

```
void init_array(int** arrr) 
{
  (*arrr) = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  // ... 
}

int main() 
{ 
  int* arr = NULL;
  init_array(&arr); //< pass reference to arr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
int lenght = find_lenght(arrr);
```

may invoke undefined behavior, because `find_length` requires its argument to be a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated `int` array. However, the content of the memory pointed to by `arrr` is indeterminate, because it has not been initialized. Therefore, it is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pointer to pointer to `int` to change passed pointer. Your `for` loop is invalid in print function. You need also to set the sentinel value yourself.

```
size_t find_length(const int *arrr)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    if(arrr)
        while(arrr[i]) i++;
    return i;
}

void add_element(int **arrr, int element)
{
    size_t length = find_length(*arrr);
    int *tmp = realloc(*arrr, (length + 2) * sizeof(**arrr));
    
    if(tmp)
    {
        *arrr = tmp;
        (*arrr)[length] = element;
        (*arrr)[length + 1] = 0;
    }
}

void print_array(const int *arrr)
{
    printf("Array elements are:\n");
    size_t lenght = find_length(arrr);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < lenght; i++) 
    {
        printf("arrr[%zu] = %d\n", i, arrr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int *arr = NULL;
    add_element(&arr, 5);
    add_element(&arr, 15);
    add_element(&arr, 25);
    add_element(&arr, 35);
    print_array(arr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/drKej3KT5

Answer (score 1):

the array on your main function is still NULL. the better way to do is just call the print_array() function after you initialize it. you just simply put     print_array(arrr) inside init_array() and after the for loop statement.